# Why does the spring/mvc project look for a jsp page to display the output?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, java-8

I created the an application looking at the example from https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/. I placed the exact same code for Greetings.java and GreetingController.java. And when I run the code it is looking for a JSP page. But according to the example there is no need for a jsp page? Why am I getting this error? I created a Spring-MVC project in intelliJ 14.0 with Application server option. Below image shows the project type I chose in IntelliJ. Please advice how I can overcome this error.

[image]

Below is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.springapp</groupId>
<artifactId>FirstSpringApp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>FirstSpringApp</name>

<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>FirstSpringApp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Given below is my web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Below is my class Greeting.java

```
public class Greeting {

private final long id;
private final String content;

public Greeting(long id, String content) {
    this.id = id;
    this.content = content;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}
}
```

And below is my code GreetingController.java

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {



    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
            String.format(template, name));
}
}
```

Comment: if u have used view resolver?please make sure what is suffix property of ur resolver bean?

Comment: I edited the question with my pom.xml. I am new to all these. Please help

Comment: share ur web.xml as well as configuration xml  file.

Comment: I have added that as well...

Comment: @JBNizet like if i post my code can u answer?

Comment: If you post your code, we'll be able to find for a bug in your code and know what it's doing. Without code, we can't. Isn't that obvious? Are *you* able to debug code without seeing any line of it?

Comment: Added the code as well

Comment: What do you mean by "when I run the code"? Which URL are you typing in the address bar of your browser? And what exact message do you get?